# Add field to SPList default view

Tags: sharepoint, list, view, splist

I've created an SPList instance with some custom fields. But When I'm viewing this list in sharepoint (default view), only Title column shows up. How can I add my columns to default view of my newly created list?

I tried:

```
list.Fields.Add("Foo", SPFieldType.Text, true):
list.View[0].ViewFields.Add("Foo");
list.View[0].Update();
list.Update();
```

But doesnt work.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

It won't work due to the fact that `list.view[0]` returns a **new** SPView on every call; see [here](http://solutionizing.net/2009/02/21/why-you-need-reflector-splist-defaultview/). In your case you call `update()` on a new instance.

To make it work, store the view in a variable and add the field to that view. (Example is for default view, but `list.View[0]` should also work)

```
SPView view = list.DefaultView;
view.ViewFields.Add("Foo");
view.Update();
```

Comment: No problem, I've struggled with this myself too.

Comment: Ugh kill me now SharePoint! Way to totally break the idea of properties.